# Win 7 64 bit on a Gateway SX2840 stuck on identifying network - wireless or wired - no Internet connection

Tags: windows-7, windows, networking

this is the second time this has happened on this system - the first time I just ended up using a system restore and started fresh - I saw this thread already and tried all that stuff:

[Windows-7 Ultimate 64 bit wont connect to my wired/wireless networks](https://superuser.com/questions/100553/windows-7-ultimate-64-bit-wont-connect-to-my-wired-wireless-networks)

I have disabled IPv6 , set the old vista DHCP broadcast enabled reg key , turned off the firewall via the policy editor , uninstalled AV and anything else I thought might be blocking the connection , I uninstalled any updates that were applied between the time it worked and stopped working  -

not sure what else to try I think I have read every thread on every forum and tried every suggestion -

I plugged in a wireless usb dongle and get the same results - will be trying a USB to Ethernet adapter later today

I also tried assigning a static IP and no luck

It just stays on identifying-

Comment: Can you clarify a bit more precisely. It hangs while trying to detect the list of wireless networks available? Do other machines show at least one wireless network available?

Comment: so it connects - but never gets far enough to get to the outside world - it can even see other systems on the network - but cant connect to them - the identifying network swirl just swirls endlessly in the network and sharing center and there is an X between the system and internet - so net net - it connects but can't get out to the rest of the world -

Comment: Is it configured to get its IP address automatically? If so, is it getting an IP address? What does 'ipconfig /all' show?

Comment: it gets a 169 address (I forget the exact address and its disconnected at the moment)which is the standard  address given when Windows can get out to the internet - also a USB to Ethernet adapter displays the same behavior - really messed up - about to rebuild again

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

1. Open an elevated command prompt
2. Type `netsh int ip reset` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
3. Then type `netsh winsock reset` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
4. Restart